# Django: admin.py doesn't exist?

Tags: django

In DjangoBook, it says that the every books app should have its own admin.py. However, none of my apps have there own separate admin.py as the text suggests. I was just wondering if this is a Django 1.3 thing and if so, where is the admin.py data stored now, if not in a separate admin.py file?

The chapter I'm referring to is here:
http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06/

P.S. I'm not talking about django-admin.py

Comment: that paragraph would be the perfect spot for the classic style of statement like "the observant user will realize that this file doesn't exist, yet." If you keep reading that chapter it should guide you through activating the admin site and creating the admin.py file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default there is no admin.py file created for you when you create a new app, you will need to create your own. Here are the directions on how to create the admin.py file.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/

Edit: 1.3 is no longer supported, here is a link to 1.8:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/

Answer (score 2):

You need to create admin.py in new app and edit it with 
**from django.contrib import admin**
In project/urls.py, in my case (mysite/urls.py) specify the url of newapp/admin (polls/admin) like
**from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 from django.contrib import admin 

admin.autodiscover() 
urlpatterns = patterns('',url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),)**